# Text alignment breaks immediately after new page

Tags: page, alignment

So basically the picture below tells a thousand words.

[image]

Why does alignment break immediately after entering new page and how do I fix this ?

Comment: Welcome. You're going to need to provide at least a minimal example with some code "to fix". May I suggest that you add more details and state your question more precisely.

Comment: A picture may indeed sometimes say more than a thousand words. But a picture is still no substitute -- at least not on this site -- for compilable (La)TeX code. :-(

Comment: Besides posting a complete minimal example that reproduces the issue, could you also explain what you mean by 'alignment'? Can you describe what the problem with the current behavior is, and what you would like to change? And, welcome to TeX.SE of course!

Comment: many (although not all) document classes assume `twoside` mode and align the alternate pages differently to allow for duplexing and binding.  perhaps that is what you are seeing.

Comment: the page break looks fine more worrying is the text that is going past (4) but without any code shown you make it very hard to guess the issue.